# Retrofit cannot be provided without an @Inject constructor or from an @Provides- or @Produces-annotated method

Tags: android, dependency-injection, retrofit, dagger, dagger-2

I am learning Dagger 2 now and it's such a pain for me to explain the question without codes , so let me list all my modules, components and etc first :

---

App.class

```
public class App extends Application {

private ApiComponent mApiComponent = null;
private AppComponent mAppComponent = null;

public ApiComponent getApiComponent() {
    if (mApiComponent == null) {
        // Dagger%COMPONENT_NAME%
        mApiComponent = DaggerApiComponent.builder()
                // list of modules that are part of this component need to be created here too
                .appModule(new AppModule(this)) // This also corresponds to the name of your module: %component_name%Module
                .apiModule(new ApiModule(this))
                .build();

    }
    return mApiComponent;
}

public AppComponent getAppComponent() {
    if (mAppComponent == null) {
        // If a Dagger 2 component does not have any constructor arguments for any of its modules,
        // then we can use .create() as a shortcut instead:
        mAppComponent = DaggerAppComponent.builder()
                .appModule(new AppModule(this))
                .build();

    }
    return mAppComponent;
}
}
```

---

AppComponent

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules = AppModule.class)
public interface AppComponent {
    void inject(RetrofitDemo target);
}
```

---

AppModule

```
    private final Application mContext;

AppModule(Application context) {
    mContext = context;
}

@Singleton
@ForApplication
@Provides
Application provideApplication() {
    return mContext;
}

@Singleton
@ForApplication
@Provides
Context provideContext() {
    return mContext;
}
```

---

ApiComponent

```
@Singleton
@Component(dependencies = {AppModule.class},modules =    {ApiModule.class})
public interface ApiComponent {
     void inject(RetrofitDemo target);
}
```

---

APIModule

```
@Inject
Context application;

@Inject
public ApiModule(Context context){
    this.application = context;
}

@Provides
@Singleton
Gson provideGson() {
    return new GsonBuilder()
            // All timestamps are returned in ISO 8601 format:
            .setDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'")
            // Blank fields are included as null instead of being omitted.
            .serializeNulls()
            .create();
}


@Provides
@Singleton
OkHttpClient provideOkHttpClient() {
  ...
}



@Provides
@Singleton
public Retrofit provideRetrofit(Gson gson,OkHttpClient okHttpClient){
  return new Retrofit.Builder()
          .baseUrl(DribbleApi.END_POINT)
          .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
          .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJavaCallAdapterFactory.create())
          .client(okHttpClient)
          .build();
}
```

---

And my activity will be like this:

```
    @Inject
Retrofit mRetrofit;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_retrofit_demo);
    ((App) getApplication()).getApiComponent().inject(this);
...
```

---

Here is the error message:

```
Error:(18, 10) : retrofit2.Retrofit cannot be provided without an @Inject constructor or from an @Provides- or @Produces-annotated method.
retrofit2.Retrofit is injected at com.sinyuk.yuk.RetrofitDemo.mRetrofit
com.sinyuk.yuk.RetrofitDemo is injected at com.sinyuk.yuk.AppComponent.inject(target)
```

What makes me confused is the retrofit instance is provided by the ApiModule, but why the error massage said it's injected at appComponent?And I can't find any place wrong in my code. T_T,it's too heavy going to learn Dagger for me...I think.

---

Besides, in my case I wrote `dependencies = AppModule.class  module = ApiModule.class` in the AppComponent , and it seems to be right I think,but if I wrote `module = ({AppComponent.class,ApiComponent.class})`,it also works fine.Anybody can explain me why?

---

Kindly review  my code and give me some advice. Thx in advance!

Answer (score 5):

@Sinyuk There's a lot to unpack here, and Dagger is a little complicated at first blush, but I think I can help.  First, you have a conceptual misunderstanding regarding the `@Component` annotation. A `Component` is an interface which you define, and which Dagger implements through code generation.  You will define the interface, and annotate it with `@Component` and then you will provide a set of `Module`s to Dagger to use in the generation process.  The modules which you use are passed in through the `modules` element of the `@Component` annotation.  If you want to have one `Component` permit another `Component` to support the injection process, then any `Component` interfaces which you need to have Dagger use while injecting your code, will be passed in through the `dependencies` element of the `@Component` annotation.

--

As a result, The following is incorrect

```
@Component(dependencies = AppModule.class  module = ApiModule.class`)
```

instead, to have the one Component use two Modules write:

```
@Component(modules = {ApiModule.class, AppModule.class})
```

or, to have one Component use one Module and depend upon the other Component

```
@Component(modules = {AppModule.class}, dependencies = {ApiComponent.class})
```

I hope that that helps you get onto the right path.  Let me know if you have any follow up questions.

Answer (score 1):

Okay so your configuration should be this

```
public class App extends Application {
    private AppComponent mAppComponent = null;

    public AppComponent getAppComponent() {
        if (mAppComponent == null) {
            // If a Dagger 2 component does not have any constructor arguments for any of its modules,
            // then we can use .create() as a shortcut instead:
            mAppComponent = DaggerAppComponent.builder()
                .appModule(new AppModule(this))
                .build();

        }
        return mAppComponent;
    }
}
```

And

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules = {AppModule.class, ApiModule.class})
public interface AppComponent {
    void inject(RetrofitDemo target);
}
```

And

```
@Module
public class AppModule {
    private final Application mContext;

    AppModule(Application context) {
        mContext = context;
    }

    @Provides
    Application provideApplication() {
        return mContext;
    }

    @Provides
    Context provideContext() {
        return mContext;
    }
}
```

And

```
@Module
public class ApiModule {
    @Provides
    @Singleton
    Gson provideGson() {
          return new GsonBuilder()
            // All timestamps are returned in ISO 8601 format:
            .setDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'")
            // Blank fields are included as null instead of being omitted.
            .serializeNulls()
            .create();
    }


    @Provides
    @Singleton
    OkHttpClient provideOkHttpClient() {
          ...
    }



    @Provides
    @Singleton
    public Retrofit provideRetrofit(Gson gson, OkHttpClient okHttpClient){
      return new Retrofit.Builder()
         .baseUrl(DribbleApi.END_POINT)
         .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
         .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJavaCallAdapterFactory.create())
         .client(okHttpClient)
         .build();
    }
}
```

And

```
//...Activity

@Inject
Retrofit mRetrofit;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_retrofit_demo);
    ((App) getApplication()).getAppComponent().inject(this);
...
```